# Error @OneToOne or @ManyToOne references an unknown entity

Tags: jpa

I receive an error like below and I do not know why?

> Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne
>   on ##################.model.Orders.customerid references an unknown
>   entity: java.lang.Long

**Class Orders**

```
@Entity
public class Orders {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long orderid;
  @JoinColumn(name = "customerid", referencedColumnName = "CustomerID")
  @ManyToOne
  private Long customerid;
  @JoinColumn(name = "employeeid", referencedColumnName = "EmployeeID")
  @ManyToOne
  private Long employeeid;
  private java.sql.Timestamp orderdate;
  private java.sql.Timestamp requireddate;
  private java.sql.Timestamp shippeddate;
  @JoinColumn(name = "shipperid", referencedColumnName = "ShipperID")
  @ManyToOne
  private Long shipvia;
  private Double freight;
  private String shipname;
  private String shipaddress;
  private String shipcity;
  private String shipregion;
  private String shippostalcode;
  private String shipcountry;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="orderid")
  private List<OrderDetails> orderDetails;
```

Class Customers

```
@Entity
public class Customers {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long customerid;
  private String companyname;
  private String contactname;
  private String contacttitle;
  private String address;
  private String city;
  private String region;
  private String postalcode;
  private String country;
  private String phone;
  private String fax;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="customerid")
  private List<Orders> orders;
```

Relation between this two entities are described here
[image]

Please explain me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I found the reason after asking the question I apologize for the inconvenience. As You can see I forgot to change type for customerid it should by as follows

**Class Orders**

```
@Entity
public class Orders {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long orderid;
  @JoinColumn(name = "customerid", referencedColumnName = "CustomerID")
  @ManyToOne
  private Customers customerid;
  @JoinColumn(name = "employeeid", referencedColumnName = "EmployeeID")
  @ManyToOne
  private Employees employeeid;
  private java.sql.Timestamp orderdate;
  private java.sql.Timestamp requireddate;
  private java.sql.Timestamp shippeddate;
  @JoinColumn(name = "shipperid", referencedColumnName = "ShipperID")
  @ManyToOne
  private Shippers shipvia;
  private Double freight;
  private String shipname;
  private String shipaddress;
  private String shipcity;
  private String shipregion;
  private String shippostalcode;
  private String shipcountry;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="orderid")
  private List<OrderDetails> orderDetails;
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this error recently but with an unknown entity.

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on XXXX.Terminal.location references an unknown entity: XXXX.dc.Location
Feb 06, 2020 11:51:38 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
```

In my case I had to add a mapping of this entity to the "hibernate.cfg.xml"

```
<mapping class="XXXX.dc.Location"/>
```